# Excel Data Validation B1 cannot be blank if A1 is not blank

Tags: excel

So A1 is a list, it has ignore blanks enabled because it is not required, and the values are derived from a defined name range. the source is `=procedureType`

B1 is a list that is derived from the value in A1. The source is `=CHOOSE(MATCH(A1,procedureType,0),consultType,diagnosticType,interventionalType,screeningType,therapeuticType,treatmentType)`. This works as intended. It is currently set to ignore blanks.

However, I would like to make B1 a required field IF A1 has a value in it. How do I conditionally do this? B1 is not required if A1 is blank, and it is required if A1 is not blank.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What do you mean by "required", do you want to highlight the cell, or do you want to prompt the user to actually type something in?

Comment: Good question: I mean to have the user forced to enter a value if the first column has a value. I'm hoping for the data validation to throw an error if the first column has a value and the second does not.

Comment: The only way I can think of to "require" input in any cell in Excel is to get fairly draconian. Namely, until B has a value for the row in question, you'd need to set the `.Locked` property of EVERY cell EXCEPT the one to be filled to `TRUE` and password protect the worksheet. You'd have to use a macro to do this. Without that, the best you can do is point out that a "required" value is missing with a highlight like @MarcoGetrost mentioned, or something like that.